# Gracefully interrupt jupyter kernel through jupyter_client API

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-console

My aim is to connect to a running `jupyter qtconsole` using the `jupyter_client` API and to execute commands on that kernel remotely. Execution of code works but it seems not possible to interrupt running code from the kernel frontend using `Ctrl-C` (either in `qtconsole` or `console`). Below my sample code with I execute in a different instance of `qtconsole` and that can't be interrupted:

```
import jupyter_client as jc

# Find last accessed connection file
cfile = jc.find_connection_file()
km = jc.KernelManager()
km.load_connection_file(connection_file=cfile)
kc.start_channels()

msg = """
import time
for k in range(10):
    print(k)
    time.sleep(1)
"""
kc.execute(msg)
```

The only way I found to interrupt the execution is to send a `SIGINIT` directly, for example by running the following in another `jupyter` instance:

```
import os
import signal

# pid is process identifier of jupyter kernel that runs the loop
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

**Question**: Is there a more elegant way of interrupting a running kernel using the `jupyter_client` API (e.g. `KernelClient` or `KernelManager`)?

PS: There is also an open [issue](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/issues/410) on github mentioning this problem but the jupyter developers haven't been very responsive so far.